# Differentiating both sides of an inequality with monotonic functions

Tags: calculus, inequality, derivatives

If $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all real $x$ for monotonic functions $f$ and $g$ (say, both increasing), does it follow that $f'(x)\le g'(x)$?

(Note: I've seen several questions asking the same thing without the condition of monotonicity, but the counterexamples given always involve a non-monotonic function, and it seems to me that this condition might be sufficient; I haven't been able to come up with any counterexamples myself.)

If not, is the stronger condition that $f^{(n)}(x)$ and $g^{(n)}(x)$ are monotone for either all natural $n$ or all $n\le N$ for some $N$ sufficient?

Comment: by $f(x)\le g(x)$, do you mean for all reals?

Comment: @grdgfgr Yes, sorry, edited.

Comment: Hm, $2\arctan x$ and $(\arctan x) + 3\pi$ ?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/LtOriF5.png

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin There goes my idea; I do notice that $\arctan' x=\frac 1{x^2+1}$ is not monotone. Could the stronger condition still by sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Take any two $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $f'(x)>g'(x)$ over some domain $D$.

Then $\bar f(x):=f(x)-\max_{x\in D} f(x)$ and $\bar g(x):= g(x)-\min_{x\in D} g(x)$ are such that
$$\bar f(x)\le\bar g(x)$$and
$$\bar f'(x)>\bar g'(x).$$

Comment: Is the stronger condition sufficient?

Comment: @Laertes: you should see for yourself that the above reasoning will "resist" to the stronger condition.

Answer (score 3):

Another more explicit example:
$$
f(x)=x-\frac\pi2+\arctan x,\quad g(x)=x.
$$
$$
f'(x)=1+\frac{1}{1+x^2},\quad g'(x)=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The question can be reformulated with $f(x)\le0$ and $f'(x)\le0$, without loss of generality.

Obviously, the growth of a function doesn't tell you its sign, as any added constant disappears by derivation.

Anyway, a starting function value can settle the case:

$$f'(x)\le0\land f(a)\le 0\implies\forall x\ge a: f(x)\le 0.$$